# The sign of $-4\eta ^2\cosh\beta\cosh(\beta\eta)-4\eta\sinh\beta\sinh(\beta\eta)+2B^2\cosh(2\beta\eta)+2B^2+4$

Tags: trigonometry, problem-solving, hyperbolic-functions

Can I figure out when the sign of this expression is positive and when it is negative?

$$-4 \eta ^2 \cosh (\beta ) \cosh (\beta  \eta )-4 \eta  \sinh (\beta ) \sinh (\beta  \eta )+2 B^2 \cosh (2 \beta  \eta )+2 B^2+4$$
where $\eta =\sqrt{B^2+1}$, and $\beta>0$.

Comment: Can one eliminate $B$ by $B^2 = \eta^2 - 1$?

Comment: @RiverLi Yes, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hint #1: $\eta$ (by definition) is positive for all values of $B$, so everything to the right of the hyperbolic functions will be positive.

Hint #2: Factor out $-4 \eta$ and take note of the signs of each of the hyperbolic equations.

Comment: I forgot to mention that $\beta >0$, Please see the edit, thank you.

Comment: Are there any ideas

Comment: If there were an extra $\eta$ in this equation, you'd get an easy factoring - $$-4\eta^2 (\cosh (\beta(1-\eta))$$...